# Calling a Selenium Testcase in python

Tags: python, selenium, python-unittest

I'm trying to run a selenium testcase in python. I have testcases that I can run directly from the command line no problem with

```
python seleniumtest.py
```

However when I try to run it from within python it is failing.

```
__import__('seleniumtest')
```

seleniumtest.py ends with a command

```
unittest.main()
```

this command seems to fail when it gets run using the `__import__` method. Does know why running this through the import is not working? For my purposes I cannot simply use `popen`.

Comment: How do i avoid having the __import__ become bold?

Comment: i doubt that *import* bolded automatically.. if you want to have it monospace, like code, just enclose it in backticks `

Comment: import became bold because `__` outside a code area are makes bold text

Comment: @leoluk the question was how I avoid it, not why :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have something like this at the end of your selenium program:

```
if __name__=="__main__"
```